# Get Two Dimensional Array from select boxes Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the above to display in this manner:

```
 csecsub[0][0]={'NYU', 'Additional Mathematics', '3'}

 csecsub[0][1]={'NYU', 'Agricultural Science DA', '1'}

 csecsub[1][0]={'MIT', Agricultural Science DA', '1'}

 csecsub[1][1]={'MIT', Agricultural Science SA', '1'}
```

I have tried using_.map but i keep getting _.map is not a function. even when i include lodash.min.js. I would really like to figure out how to accomplish the above. Thanks in advance. so with the code i woulde like to dispay them as the above sample. additionally they will be displayed in an html table on the page.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").on("click",".add-morecsec",function(){ 
            var html = $(".after-add-morecsec").first().clone();     
            //  $(html).find(".change").prepend("<label for=''>&nbsp;</label><br/><a class='btn btn-danger remove'>- Remove</a>");
              $(html).find(".changecsec").html("<a class='button alert removecsec step fi-minus size-36'> Remove</a>");
          
            $(".after-add-morecsec").last().after(html); 
        });
    
        $("body").on("click",".removecsec",function(){ 
            $(this).parents(".after-add-morecsec").remove();
        });
    }); 
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("body").on("click",".add-morecsec1",function(){ 
            var html = $(".after-add-morecsec1").first().clone();     
            //  $(html).find(".change").prepend("<label for=''>&nbsp;</label><br/><a class='btn btn-danger remove'>- Remove</a>");
              $(html).find(".changecsec1").html("<a class='button alert removecsec1 step fi-minus size-36'> Remove</a>");
          
            $(".after-add-morecsec1").last().after(html); 
        });
    
        $("body").on("click",".removecsec1",function(){ 
            $(this).parents(".after-add-morecsec1").remove();
        });
    }); 

var acadachieve = $.map($('input[name*="acadachieve"]:checked'), function(e) { return e.value; });
          acadachieve = acadachieve .filter(Boolean);

    var csecsub = $.map($("select[name*=csecsub] option:selected"), function(e) {
      return e.value;
    });

    csecsub = csecsub.filter(Boolean);

    for (var i = 0; i < csecsub.length; i++) {
      if (acadachieve[i] === "csec") {
        console.log(csecsub[i]); //this is where i cannot get it to show the results i want

      }
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="School" name='school[0]' placeholder="School/College Name " />

    <input id="csec" name="acadachieve[0]" type="checkbox" value="csec" style="margin-left:20px; height: auto;" /> CSEC &nbsp;
    <input id="cape" name="acadachieve[0]" type="checkbox" value="cape" style="height: auto;" /> CAPE &nbsp;
    <input id="tertiary" name="acadachieve[0]" type="checkbox" value="cape" style="height: auto;" /> Tertiary &nbsp;

<div class="after-add-morecsec">
    <select id="csecsub" name="csecsub[0][]">
      <option value="">-Select Subject-</option>
      <option value="Additional Mathematics">Additional Mathematics</option>
      <option value="Agricultural Science DA">Agricultural Science DA</option>
      <option value="Agricultural Science SA">Agricultural Science SA</option>
    </select>

    <select id="csecgrade" name="csecgrade[0][]">
      <option value="">-Select Grade-</option>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
<div class="changecsec">
          </div>
</div>

<a class="success button add-morecsec fi-plus size-36"  name="add-morecsec">Add More Subjects</a><br><br>


    <input type="text" id="School" name='school[0]' placeholder="School/College Name " />

    <input id="csec" name="acadachieve[0]" type="checkbox" value="csec" style="margin-left:20px; height: auto;" /> CSEC &nbsp;
            <input id="cape" name="acadachieve[0]" type="checkbox" value="cape" style="height: auto;" /> CAPE &nbsp;
            <input id="tertiary" name="acadachieve[0]" type="checkbox" value="cape" style="height: auto;" /> Tertiary &nbsp;

    <div class="after-add-morecsec1">
        <select id="csecsub" name="csecsub[1][]">
          <option value="">-Select Subject-</option>
          <option value="Additional Mathematics">Additional Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Agricultural Science DA" selected>Agricultural Science DA</option>
          <option value="Agricultural Science SA">Agricultural Science SA</option>
        </select>
    
        <select id="csecgrade" name="csecgrade[1][]">
          <option value="">-Select Grade-</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
        </select>
    <div class="changecsec1">
              </div>
    </div>
<a class="success button add-morecsec1 fi-plus size-36"  name="add-morecsec1">Add More Subjects</a>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Code shown breaks due to `acadachieve` is undefined. $.map() should work fine though. Not sure how you tried using lodash map. Please try to turn this into a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: please don't down vote my question. i am trying to figure out how to get it working and i am not coming up with any solution. I also adjusted the code to add, acadachieve.

Comment: still here need help

Comment: Where are the numbers supposed to come from in your results?

Comment: i want them to come from the grade select box. If you look at the grade select box you can see there are numbers there from 1 - 5. and they should be associated with the subject chosen.

Comment: Seems this one is a hard one for this community. I have worked on my own solution it's not perfect but it is working. So I will post it shortly.

Comment: It's not a hard one at all. It's really more of an issue of a really poorly constructed question that constantly evolved the expectations

Comment: Understood I was just asking for help. If I have not constructed the code in a meaningfull manner it's me not understanding the system and how to arrange the code appearance wise.

Comment: Understand...just recognize that we all volunteer our time doing this. people are willing to help up to a point...not rewriting whole apps that keep changing. Also showing a bit of appreciation will get you more help than suggesting people are not helping you

Comment: That I know and I do appreciate what you and the community has done for me both now and the past. But I didn't mention anywhere said I didn't appreciate what the community has done for me. So we can stop going down that path. I am a programmer and task like these gives me a challenge so sometimes I seek help and other times I just can't bother and just figure it out myself. It takes me a long time but I do eventually solve it. We solve puzzles as programmers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code below shows how i got it to display in the manner below:

```
      csecsub[0][0]={'NYU', 'Additional Mathematics', '3'}

      csecsub[0][1]={'NYU', 'Agricultural Science DA', '1'}

      csecsub[1][0]={'MIT', Agricultural Science DA', '1'}

      csecsub[1][1]={'MIT', Agricultural Science SA', '1'}
```

The code below is kind of a mess but this is how i solved it and got it working

```js
            var acadachieve = $.map($('input[name*="acadachieve"]:checked'), function(e) { return e.value; });
            acadachieve = acadachieve.filter(Boolean);

            var school = $.map($('input[name^=school]'), function(e) { return e.value; });
            school= school.filter(Boolean);

            for(var i = 0; i < school.length; i++){
            if (acadachieve[i]==="csec") {
 

            var $csecsub = $("select[name*=csecsub] option:selected");
            var $csecgrade = $("select[name*=csecgrade] option:selected");
       

            var school1 ="";
            var z=0;
            var x=0;
            var loop=0;
            var results=[];
            var results1=[];
            var hm="";
            var hm1="";

            while(z<1){

            results = $.map($csecsub,function(el, i) {
            if($(el).closest('.scoolWrapperClass0').find('input[name*=school]').val()!=undefined && el.value!="" ){
            return [[ school1 = $(el).closest('.scoolWrapperClass0').find('input[name*=school]').val(),   el.value, $csecgrade.eq(i).val()]]    
            }
            });
            results=results.filter(Boolean);


            results1 = $.map($csecsub,function(el, i) {
            if($(el).closest('.scoolWrapperClass1').find('input[name*=school]').val()!=undefined && el.value!=""){
            return [[ school1 = $(el).closest('.scoolWrapperClass1').find('input[name*=school]').val(),   el.value, $csecgrade.eq(i).val()]]
            }
            });
            results1=results1.filter(Boolean);



            //write the result to a table in html
            hm+=('<tr style="width: 100%;"><th style="border: 2px solid black; color: #2199e8; width: 40%;"> School/College </th> <th style="border: 2px solid black; color: #2199e8; width: 10%;"> Academic Achievment </th><th style="border: 2px solid black; color: #2199e8; width: 30%;"> Subject </th> <th style="border: 2px solid black; color: #2199e8; width: 20%;"> Grade </th></tr>');
            z++;
            }


            ///loop one for first school

            for(loop = 0; loop < results.length; loop++){
            //alert(results[loop].toString().split(","));
            try { ///exception handling

            //write the result to a table in html
            hm+=('<tr style="width: 100%;" ><td  style="border: 2px solid black; width: 40%;" >'+results[loop].toString().split(",")[0]+'</td> <td  style="border: 2px solid black; width: 10%;" >' + acadachieve[i]+ '</td> <td  style="border: 2px solid black; width: 30%;" >' + results[loop].toString().split(",")[1] + '</td> <td  style="border: 2px solid black; width: 20%;" >' + results[loop].toString().split(",")[2]+ '</td></tr>');


            $('#display_achievment').html(hm);

            }
            catch (e) {
            if (!(e instanceof TypeError)) {
            // The exception is not a TypeError, so throw it again.
            throw e;
            }
            }

            }

            ///loop two for second school 

            for(loop = 0; loop < results1.length; loop++){
            try {



            hm1+=('<tr style="width: 100%;" ><td  style="border: 2px solid black; width: 40%;" >'+results1[loop].toString().split(",")[0]+'</td> <td  style="border: 2px solid black; width: 10%;" >' + acadachieve[i]+ '</td> <td  style="border: 2px solid black; width: 30%;" >' + results1[loop].toString().split(",")[1] + '</td> <td  style="border: 2px solid black; width: 20%;" >' + results1[loop].toString().split(",")[2]+ '</td></tr>');


            $('#display_achievment1').html(hm1);

            }
            catch (e) {
            if (!(e instanceof TypeError)) {
            // The exception is not a TypeError, so throw it again.
            throw e;
            }
            }



            }

            }
            }

            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is basically what you are looking for. There is nothing showing in example results relating to the checkboxes so that part is very unclear

```js
var $csecsub = $("select[name*=csecsub]"),
  $csecgrade = $("select[name*=csecgrade]"),

  results = $.map($csecsub,function(el, i) {    
    return [[el.value, $csecgrade.eq(i).val()]]
  })

console.log(results)
```

```html
<input id="csec" name="acadachieve[0]" type="checkbox" value="csec" style="margin-left:20px; height: auto;" /> CSEC &nbsp;
<input id="cape" name="acadachieve[0]" type="checkbox" value="cape" style="height: auto;" /> CAPE &nbsp;
<input id="tertiary" name="acadachieve[0]" type="checkbox" value="cape" style="height: auto;" /> Tertiary &nbsp;


<select id="csecsub" name="csecsub[0][]">
  <option value="">-Select Subject-</option>
  <option value="Additional Mathematics" selected>Additional Mathematics</option>
  <option value="Agricultural Science DA">Agricultural Science DA</option>
  <option value="Agricultural Science SA">Agricultural Science SA</option>
</select>

<select id="csecgrade" name="csecgrade[0][]">
  <option value="">-Select Grade-</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select id="csecsub" name="csecsub[1][]">
  <option value="">-Select Subject-</option>
  <option value="Additional Mathematics">Additional Mathematics</option>
  <option value="Agricultural Science DA" selected>Agricultural Science DA</option>
  <option value="Agricultural Science SA">Agricultural Science SA</option>
</select>

<select id="csecgrade" name="csecgrade[1][]">
  <option value="">-Select Grade-</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4" selected>4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thanks much now how would i print it out say school for example an array of school goes beside each of them.  say:::  Array [ "School Name", "English A", "1" ]

Comment: where does that come from? Is it indexed the same way as the selects are?

Comment: it is a single array and it goes with the subject at [0] and the next with the subject at[1].    <input type="text" id="School" name='school[0]' />   so if the person enters New York University it should go with everything in csecsub[0]   and so on if they enter Florida University it should go with csecsub[1]

Comment: Oh yeah. Quick note. Can't repeat ID's in a page. They are unique by definition. If you change all those ID's to classes can modify to `var $schools = $('.schoolInputClass')` then update `return [[$schools.eq(i).val(),el.value, $csecgrade.eq(i).val()]]`

Comment: i know i ca't repeat id but i used the input name of the school. but i still have an problem the one school is repeating with all the subjects and grade. they should be associated with their respectful subject and grade.

Comment: Narrow it down to a [mcve], Can use really simple names like "abc","cde"  even

Comment: i added it. i also have a button there that generate additional subject and grade select boxes so you will know the full extent of what i am trying to accomplish.

Comment: So the whole group of elements in your current demo will be repeated multiple times as in multiple schools each with same set of checkboxes, selects etc repeated for each school??

Comment: Wrap the whole set into parent container then. To get the school value would do something like `var school = $(el).closest('.scoolWrapperClass').find('.schoolInputClass').val()`

Comment: I tried something and got it working I was on it for hours. Gave me an headache. Gonna post my answer since your not updating your answer to match my needs

Comment: Scope of this has changed several times. Please understand that Stackoverflow is not a free code writing service and to expect someone to *"match your needs"* is a bit over reaching

Comment: Ok noted and I understand. That's why I came up with a solution of my own. I was just asking for help.